# In Exchange 2010 what are 'Database copies' and how do they relate to Exchange 2007 Storage Groups?

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a Exchange 2007 server with 3 databases and a Exchange 2010 server with one new database. Firstly I'm unable to create a new database on the Exchange 2010 server, I see no button or command to do this and where I would expect to find the 'Storage Groups' I see 'Database copies', what is the difference between the two and how are they related? I would like to create another database on the 2010 server and move the users over from 2007 but I can't see how to create another database. I'm puzzled!

Thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, what happened to reading documentation?

I suggest a little read in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298136.aspx

Storage groups are retired, did not work.

Database copies  are that - backup copies of databases. You can basically have:

- Multiple copies on the same computer AND
- Copy a database to another computer via queue

which, all in all, gives you pretty much a "never need the backup" scenario.

Now, creating another database is not exactly hard...
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298136.aspx has the command line methods for that.